# F# interface specifying a generic return type

Tags: f#

How can I accomplish the following C# in F#

```cs
public interface IExample
{
  int GetInteger();
  T GetAnything<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The F# translation would be something like this

```ml
type IExample = 
    interface
        abstract member GetInt: unit -> int

        abstract member GetAnything: unit -> 'T
    end
```

Comment: sadly, no, in that case, 'T can't be inferred when implementing IExample, it always expects 'T regardless of the return type of the implementation of `GetAnything`. e.g: ig GetAnything returns a string, then it complains it expected `'T` not `string`

Comment: Well, yeah, but that is also the case for the C# implementation that you showed. Maybe what you want is `IExample<T>`?